# How do i create a switch for responsive devices?

Tags: block-editor, mobile

i found a plugin with the use of this component. It creates a switch for desktop, tablet and mobile but i was going through every WP gutenberg component and cannot find by myself.

[image]

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for: you want a slider that has different values for different mobile devices? Or do you want a button that switches the site into different responsive widths on the page? You can find that in your browser's debug tools, and it's not something a regular user would want really unless you're deliberately presenting different views (adding or omitting UI elements) for different device types.

Comment: that component doesn't look like it comes from core/gutenberg and is custom, the closest to that is the preview menu, there's nothing stopping you from creating it using gutenberg icons, a button, a popover menu, and menu items that are just buttons with those icons though

Comment: @Rup I want to know which 'core/gutenberg' was used to get this devices switch for desktop, tablet and mobile.

Comment: @TomJNowell did you know where i find the event for the custom buttons to switch the layout view?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.